# After integer greater than 9 Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 2 supplied

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

```
def delete_Link(id):
    connection = sql_Connect()
    cursor = connection.cursor()

    cursor.execute("DELETE FROM table WHERE id =?", str(id))
    connection.commit()
```

After iterating over rows once the table id is greater than 9 I receive the following error

```
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 2 supplied.
```

Comment: The second argument is supposed to be an iterable; a string like `"10"` is an iterable that provides 2 single-character strings, `"1"` and `"0"`.

Answer (score 0):

```
def delete_Link(id):
    connection = sql_Connect()
    cursor = connection.cursor()

    cursor.execute("DELETE FROM table WHERE id =?", [id])
    connection.commit()
```

Changed the original snippet to include [] instead of () which seems to have fixed the issue. Hope this helps some others.

Answer (score 0):

Change `str(id)` to `(str(id), )` like in this example:

```
import sqlite3

def delete_link(id):
    connection = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
    cursor = connection.cursor()

    cursor.execute("DELETE FROM t WHERE id =?", (str(id),))
    connection.commit()
    print('Deleted ' + str(id))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for id in range(1, 11):
        delete_link(id)
```

Check out some examples of `.execute()` on https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html. It shows how you can send a tuple to that method in parameterized query.